# Spring JWT : How to map user permissions to accesstoken scopes

Tags: spring, jwt, access-token, scopes

I have a question concerning the mapping of my user permissions to access token scopes in spring JWT, in fact, when i map all user permissions to the accestoken scopes, and when I want to test this in my WS by @PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_USER') and #oauth2.hasScope('XXXXX')") annotation. It does not work because the checking is based on client scopes rather than user access token scopes? Is there a way, for using access token scopes (which represents my permissions user) rather than client scopes by using the #oauth2.hasScope('XXXXX') annotation? how can i do that?

Answer (score 2):

I think your user roles should be mapped to authorities in your AuthenticationProvider by overriding mapAuthorities, then you could use:
    PreAuthorize("hasRole('XXXX')")
or
    PreAuthorize("hasAuthority('XXXX')")